# Effective way to handle null in visitor pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

Imagine you have a collection of objets and you use the Visitor pattern - how would you handle null retrieved from the collection most elegantly?

Comment: Why put nulls there in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either your problem requires some special type of visitable objects or you're trying to impose too many responsibilities on your visitor pattern.
If you really have meaningful object which must not be visited try **Null Object** pattern.

```
public class NullElement implements Element {

    public void accept(ElementVisitor visitor) {
        // noop
    }
}
```

Comment: +1.  Nicer than having every visitor check for null.  Of course a Visitor whose job was to count the nulls wouldn't work - but you can find ways around that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any way other than putting an `if (element != null) element.accept(visitor);`

If you're using guava or something, you could of course do a [`filter`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/guava/guava/r03/guava-r03-javadoc.jar!/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#filter%28java.util.Set,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) but it seems like an overkill.

Comment: Or if you are passing the elements to the visitor's `visit()` method, just check for `null` as the first step and skip it.